# RESTful put id and body

Tags: java, json, rest, put

I need to have my Java server receive a PUT request to create a new user from an id and a json body, the URI needs to be like:

```
/usermanagement/user/$id { "name":john, "type":admin }
```

Given that I've made a simple Java class and can later convert the JSON to a POJO using Jackson, here's my problem:
How do I specify the PUT request to accept both the id and the JSON body as parameters? So far I've got:

```
 @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public String createUser(@PathParam("id") int id){
        User user = new User();  
        User.setId(id);

        return SUCCESS_MSG;
    }
```

And this works, but I've had no luck adding the JSON body and having the function parse it. I've tried:

```
public String createUser(@PathParam("id") int id, String body){
     return body;
}
```

It should return the same input JSON when testing in Postman, however it always returns a "resource not available" error.

I feel there's something obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: I think you need to add an undecorated parameter to receive your body.  `public String createUser(@PathParam("id") int id, String body)`

Comment: That's the first thing I've tried, it always gives me a "Resource not available" error when executing the query.

Comment: Sounds more like a library issue than your code, but I'm guessing - sorry

Comment: Are you sure you want your user to define the IDs? I would go for `POST` and database generated IDs.

Comment: The generation method is irrelevant at this point, this is only for a college assignment

Answer (score 1):

As per REST API conventions, a POST method on a uri like /usermanagement/users is what is needed.  PUT method is used for updating an existing resource.  You can go through this wonderful article on how to design pragmatic RESTful API.  http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api.

If you are trying to create a new user, why give it an ID?  You have to POST the data such as user name, lastname, email, ... and let the backend generate an ID (like an auto-incremented id, or some UUUID) for this new resource.

For example, in my app, I use a json body for a POST request like below:

```
  {
    "loginId":    "ravi.sharma",
    "firstName":  "Ravi",
    "lastName":   "Sharma",
    "email":      "myemail@email.com",
    "contactNo":  "919100000001",
    "..." : ".."
  }
```

Moreover, your response should return HTTP-201, after successful creation, and it should contain a location header, pointing to the newly created resource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the specification implicitly said to use PUT for creation. Also, it needs to return a pre-defined JSON which I've hardcoded as static variables.

Comment: @Flopn If you're using PUT to create new resources then you're implicitly allowing clients to own the URI space. That can become problematic over time, particularly if you ever want to modify your URI structure somehow, which is why POST is the best operation for creating new resources. Are you sure you want to use PUT rather than question the specification?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using String body, use a Class with Member variables name and Type Like this.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

(This works in Spring Boot Web out-of-box. incase of Spring MVC, you might need to add Jackson dependency): On your Controller , Add @RequestBody Annotation, then Jackson will take care of the un-marshaling of JSON String to User Object.

```
public String createUser(@PathParam("id") int id, @RequestBody User user){
```